# Python Bottle - jQuery AJAX success function response is HTML

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, bottle, locals

I am having an issue with Python Bottle and the jQuery AJAX function. Right now, when I try to use the AJAX call after a button submission call (via the `jQuery.submit()` function), the data that is passed back is the entire HTML text.

On the Bottle side, I have code that looks as such:

```
@route('/testing')
@view('test.tpl')
def test():
    myDict = request.query.decode()
    data = 100
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = []
    if myDict:
         c.append(myDict['var1'])
         c.append(myDict['var2'])
         return json.dumps(c)
    return locals()
```

On the JS side, I have code that looks as such:

```
$('#buttonSubmit').submit(function(d) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', // I get that this is redundant
        // dataType: 'json',
        url: '/testing?var1=test1&var2=test2',
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
    });
});
```

On the HTML side, I have code that looks as such:

```
<form id='buttonSubmit'>
    <button type='submit'>Go</button>
</form>
```

My assumption is that when I click the button, it makes the AJAX call, which goes to the Python file via the Bottle interface. In this .py file, it will then make the `test()` call and return a dictionary of the local values (via `locals()`). However, when I log into console the 'data' object that is passed back, it turns out to be the entire HTML file (including  tags).

My question is: why is this the case? I have figured out that the responseText for the jqXHR object matches the data that is given to the success function callback.

**EDIT:**

Let me explain the general flow of this. I begin by loading the `/testing` page. Upon doing so, the `test.tpl` template file renders fine and the Python file returns the `locals()` dictionary. However, after this page is loaded, when an AJAX call is fired, I have it go to this same `test()` Bottle method with a query. In response to this AJAX query, `locals()` will  still return the same data, but the data that will be returned to the JS (the data belonging to the `success` callback function) will now be the entire HTML text, as opposed to a dictionary.

However, if I were to change this and have a separate return (i.e. `return json.dumps(c)`), then the data registered will be a JSON file (once I add in the `dataType='json'` part. So I guess herein lies my confusion. What is different about AJAX that causes this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That route is configured to return a view, not a JSON dict.  If you comment out this line, then it will return a dict instead:

```
@view('test.tpl')
```

---

`view` renders the template only when the response is a dict.  When it's a string (as in your response from `json.dumps`), it just passes the result through unmodified:

```
% pydoc bottle.view

bottle.view = view(tpl_name, **defaults)
    Decorator: renders a template for a handler.
    The handler can control its behavior like that:

      - return a dict of template vars to fill out the template
      - return something other than a dict and the view decorator will not
        process the template, but return the handler result as is.
        This includes returning a HTTPResponse(dict) to get,
        for instance, JSON with autojson or other castfilters.
```

Comment: I tried commenting the line out, and it does indeed return a dictionary instead. However, it no longer registers the 'test.tpl' template. I want it to still register the template, while returning a dictionary.
The thing is, it does that for the initial loading of the page. When I return the `locals()` (local vars), it will then register them in the template when I reference the variables with double braces (`{{}}`). But upon an AJAX call, no luck.

Comment: Are you expecting different behaviour from the same code, in the case of GET vs POST?  In that case you might try creating two routes that are identical, except one uses `method='GET'` and the other uses `method='POST'`.  The `GET` method would register the template whereas the `POST` method would not (so as to return a dict).

Comment: I am expecting the same behavior from the Python Bottle code. I always want it to return a dictionary. My confusion lies in how the template renders itself. The very first time I load the page (no AJAX calls yet), I use the inline `{{}}` in my template file to grab values from the dictionary `locals()` that is returned by my Python method.
However, after the AJAX 'get' call, it changes and the value returned by my Python call is the full HTML code. That's where my confusion lies.

Comment: I'm confused by this: "I want it to still register the template, while returning a dictionary."  How can you expect both from identical calls?  Either the return value is HTML (via template), or JSON (no template).  Unless `test.tpl` is not an HTML template but a JSON template?

Comment: Sorry, that was a pretty vague statement. What I meant by that was that I wanted the inline statements in the template to still work, and I wanted the Python to return a dictionary.
So I just added a print statement to my Python method to see what it is returning, and it is a dictionary (this is on the initial loading of the page). `test.tpl` is a HTML template. Now, if I'm understanding things correctly, in order for the inline statements to work, I do need to return the dictionary. Now, why would AJAX cause `return locals()` to return HTML instead?

Comment: One of us is confused.  (Maybe both. :)  The way your code is written when you request `http://server:8080/testing`, your `test` method will be called. Next, `test`'s return value (a `dict`, the way you're written it) will be passed to your template, `test.tpl`, for rendering. The output of that rendering is the HTML that bottle/wsgiserver then returns to the client. That is what I'd expect your code to do--and that's indeed how you describe it to be working.  So I think your expectation is off.  Make sense?  (What am I missing?)

Comment: Again, if you want different responses (HTML when you first render the page, then JSON for your AJAX call), then you will (in general) need *two* endpoints, not one.

Comment: Hmmm, just to check, what happens upon an AJAX call then? Will the template still render an HTML that is returned to the client?
I get the two endpoints thing. It's just that I can still get a JSON response if I return it when I check that the reason the function was called was because of a query. I will edit the code above to show you what I mean.

Comment: The `bottle.view` docstring may shed some more light on what's happening.  I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I think I finally get it after reading over the documentation again. So basically, it recognizes that the request is not from a template handler, but rather an AJAX handler, and will thus read everything in as HTTP or JSON (which can be controlled from the AJAX caller's side), correct?

Comment: Happy it helped!  Well, it doesn't exactly know anything about AJAX or handlers; it just knows types.  If `isinstance(response, dict)`, then it renders the template; otherwise it just returns the non-dict response--in this case, a string.

Comment: I hope it's clear to you that your code determines the response type by virtue of checking for the existence or non-existence of query args (`if myDict:...`).  That's why you sometimes see an AJAX response (when you pass in query args) and other times a rendered HTML response (when there are no query args).